# Why there is no xml components for the action bar when we create new android studio project?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

First and foremost I am new to Android Development.

As we already know that everything that we see on the activity is a component and the source of that component is placed in the **activity_main.xml** file.

For example i have a **TextView** component:

[image]

So its xml source is here in **activity_main.xml**:

[image]

Ok everything is fine till here.

Now the confusion that i am facing is that there is an **Tool Bar** in my activity:

[image]

But there is no xml source for this **Tool Bar** in the **acitvity_main.xml**.

[image]

I wasted all my day to clear my concept but i am unable to do. There is also a file named **styles.xml** but it contains some kind of stuff in the image below:

[image]

Please can anyone tell from where this **Tool Bar** comes? I am beginner in Android Development. I will be glade to contributors to tell whats the scenario behind the scene in simple and accurate explanation?

Comment: That is the default action bar. Your theme (`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`) sets it up.

Comment: AFAIK we can only create components with java and xml, how we create components with theme? Is this theme is also xml? Can you share any internal resource where i can see the xml source of this tool bar?

Comment: Only the action bar is created by the theme.  You can also request it not to create one by selecting a theme without one.

Comment: Is this tool bar internally written in xml as well? and one more thing How this tool bar is included by the theme? Because when we include anything we use some kind of **<include .../>** tag but there is no such tag in the **activity_main.xml**.

Comment: "AFAIK we can only create components with java and xml, how we create components with theme?" -- the actual implementation of the action bar is handled by `AppCompatActivity` or a superclass. How it does that, and whether it uses layout resources or not, is up to the implementers of `AppCompatActivity` and its superclasses.

Comment: Ok so let say if i remove the whole styling from the **styles.xml** and i am extending the **AppCompatActivity** will it still show the Tool Bar? Because you mentioned that `the actual implementation of the action bar is handled by AppCompatActivity or a superclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gabe Sechan said it comes with theme and so there is no xml file where you can see its code , if you want to disappear it just write inside AppTheme style tag
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" instead of "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
 and run app you will see that action bar has gone. So its matter of theme

Comment: So, it comes with theme by default? But there should be source code where we can see the xml tags of this default tool bar at least in the default theme source code files.